# syntax for comments in github's README.md?

Tags: git, github, markdown, comments

A GitHub repo is described in a text file `README.md`, in Daring Fireball's [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) format.  Does that language support comments, either as a feature or a quick hack?  I'd like to have some text that is visible when editing the file, but invisible in the HTML result.  (Just like HTML's `<!-- ... -->`, or bash's `# ...`.)

Their extensive [example](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't seem to mention this.  Their [mailing list](https://pairlist6.pair.net/pipermail/markdown-discuss/) archive isn't directly searchable, but even [indirectly](https://www.google.com/search?q=comment+site:https://pairlist6.pair.net/pipermail/markdown-discuss/) I find only vaguely related posts.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Huh.  As a quick experiment I just tried `<!-- ... -->`, and it worked.  Here's the [example](https://github.com/uiuc-sst/PTgen/commit/be3ead9af6a5ea055156c8ba0042e1d189f02029).

Comment: Much more detail, specialized to particular programming languages, is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown.